# Script run endlessly and I cannot ctrl+C

Tags: python, python-3.x

A few days ago, this script worked perfectly and now it kind of crashes.

Here's my script, if someone wants to test it :

```py
import re
import requests
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import time
import random
import time
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait     
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By     
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


PATH = "driver\chromedriver.exe"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1200,900")
options.add_argument('enable-logging')


driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=PATH)

driver.get('https://www.tripadvisor.ca/')
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(2)


cookie = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="_evidon-accept-button"]')
try:
    cookie.click()
except:
    pass

time.sleep(2)


country = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@placeholder="Where to?"]')
country.click()
country.send_keys('London') #LOCATION TO SPECIFY
country.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(3)

sectionhotel = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@data-filter-id="LODGING"]')
sectionhotel.click()


linksfinal = []

n = 1

for x in range(n): #iterate over n pages to get the hotels links

    time.sleep(3)

    my_elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="review_count"]')

    links = [my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in my_elems]


    linksfinal = linksfinal + links

    time.sleep(3) 

    next = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="ui_button nav next primary "]')
      
    next.click()

    time.sleep(3)


j = 2 #number of pages of comments from each hotels

for url in linksfinal: 

    driver.get(url)
    
    results = requests.get(url)

    comms = []
    notes = []
    dates = []
    datestostay = []
    


    soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")

    name = soup.find('h1', class_= '_1mTlpMC3').text.strip()

    commentary = soup.find_all('div', class_='_2wrUUKlw _3hFEdNs8')

    for k in range(j): #iterate over n pages

        for container in commentary:

            comm  = container.find('q', class_ = 'IRsGHoPm').text.strip()
            comms.append(comm)


            comm1 = str(container.find("div", class_="nf9vGX55").find('span'))
            rat = re.findall(r'\d+', str(comm1))
            rat1 = (str(rat))[2]
            notes.append(rat1)

            

            datereal = container.find("div", class_= "_2fxQ4TOx").text
            datereal = datereal.replace(container.find("a", class_= "ui_header_link _1r_My98y").text, '').replace(' wrote a review',' ')
            dates.append(datereal)

            datetostay = container.find("span", class_ = "_34Xs-BQm").text
            datetostay = datetostay.replace('Date of stay:', '')
            datestostay.append(datetostay)

            time.sleep(3)

        nextpages = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="ui_button nav next primary "]')

        urlnext = nextpages.get_attribute("href")

        results2 = requests.get(urlnext)

        driver.get(urlnext)

        time.sleep(3)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(results2.text, "html.parser")

        commentary = soup.find_all('div', class_='_2wrUUKlw _3hFEdNs8')


        
    data = pd.DataFrame({
    'comms' : comms,
    'notes' : notes,
    'dates' : dates,
    'datetostay' : datestostay
    })


    try:
        data['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(data['dates']).dt.date
        data['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(data['dates'])
        data['dates'] = data.dates.dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
    except:
        pass

    try:
        data['datetostay'] = pd.to_datetime(data['datetostay']).dt.date
        data['datetostay'] = pd.to_datetime(data['datetostay'])
        data['datetostay'] = data.dates.dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
    except:
        pass


    data.to_csv(f"{name}.csv", sep=';', index=False)

    time.sleep(3)
```

The script runs endlessly and as I said in my title, I cannot ctrl+C to quit. That's so weird. Someone has an explanation ? Maybe I changed something, not on purpose though. But in this case, why cannot I quit ?

Comment: In which environment do you expect ctrl-Q to quit your Python script?  Usually in the shell the keystroke to interrupt a process is ctrl-C.

Comment: I'm on Anaconda Prompt after running the script. Usually, it works, I can quit

Comment: My bad !! It's ctrl c, I edit that. Sorry I'm stupid sometimes

Comment: The endless problem can be the time.sleep. You have some of them and one on row 122 that are inside of 3 for loops. The fastest time to run the script is 33 seconds with all the time.sleep, if it only finds one linksfinal and one commentary.

Comment: How can I solve that ? Bah deleted some of them ?

Answer (score 0):

if you cant Ctrl-C the programm then `Ctrl-AltGr-\` the programm